# Number of ways to place subset of balls between balls

Tags: probability, self-study

If there are 5 balls : b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 that have been randomly arranged what is the probability

1. 1 ball occurs between b1 and b2
2. three balls occur between b1 and b2

Here is my attempt :

```
1.
```

There 5! ways to arrange 5 balls. b3,b4 or b5 can be between b1 and b2 therefore the probability 1 ball occurs between b1 and b2 is `5! / 3`

```
2.
```

There 5! ways to arrange 5 balls. b2,b3 or b3,b4 or b3,b2 or b4,b3 or b2,b4 or or b4,b2 can be between b1 and b2 therefore the probability 2 ball occurs between b1 and b2 is `5! / 6`

Is my logic correct ? Can this be generalized to between n balls ?

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which $5!/3$ is a probability?  (You couldn't mean $3/5!$ because that's obviously far too small.)  Suggestion: make the problem by using smaller numbers of balls so you can explicitly list all the equiprobable combinations.  Often that gives insight but even when it doesn't it gives you a reliable value for checking your formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For self-study question, I gave you the answers, so that when you try, you can check if you get the correct answers.

P(0 ball occurs between b1 and b2) =       0.4
P(1 ball occurs between b1 and b2) =       0.3

P(2 ball occurs between b1 and b2) =       0.2

P(3 ball occurs between b1 and b2) =       0.1

Maybe you can begin from the printout of all 120 possible combinations, and count the number of the event, then divided by 120 to get the probability.